# Why can't your little finger move independently to your ring finger

Tags: human-biology

If you attempt to curl either your little or ring finger, you will feel a noticeable about of pressure, then the finger you try to keep stationary ends up moving as well. What keeps the two from moving independently?

Comment: This question has been asked before [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/60075/why-does-the-ring-finger-not-move-independently). Short answer is that they share muscles and nerves, which makes it difficult to move them separately.